# Spinner - different item text in pop-up/list view

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner in my Android app, that allows users to select countries. The spinner shows the ISO2 code of the selected country when folded. Here an example:

[image: Capture 1]

Once the user opens the selection pop-up list, I want to display a more extensive text for each item. So instead of displaying just "AT", the item should read "AT - Austria" as shown in the following screen-shot.

[image: Capture 2]

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

SpinnerAdapter has a getDropDownView method that can return a different view for the expanded state.